# Verifying Proof of Isomorphism between Aut Groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I have a solution, I'm tripping over myself explaining part of it. Is my solution clear? (Particularly part 2) If not, can someone help me clarify it? Thanks!

Problem:

> If a group $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, prove that $\text{Aut}(G)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Aut}(H)$

Solution:

> Let $\mathcal{G} \in \text{Aut}(G)$ and $\phi:G \rightarrow H$. By assumption $\phi$ is an isomorphism. Define: $$\Phi:\text{Aut}(G) \rightarrow \text{Aut}(H) \\ \mathcal{G} \mapsto \phi\mathcal{G}\phi^{-1}$$We want to show $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.
>
> Proceed in 3 steps: Show $\Phi$ injects, show $\Phi$ surjects, show $\Phi$ is a homomorphism.
>
> 1. Suppose $\Phi(\mathcal{G})=\Phi(\mathcal{G'})$
>      $$\Phi(\mathcal{G})=\Phi(\mathcal{G'}) \\ \implies \phi\mathcal{G}\phi^{-1} = \phi\mathcal{G}'\phi^{-1} \\ \implies \mathcal{G} = \mathcal{G'} \text{  [by taking }\phi^{-1} \text{of both sides, followed by }\phi \text{]}$$
> 2. Suppose we have $\mathcal{H} \in \text{Aut}(H)$. We want to show there exists $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\Phi(\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{H}$. Construct such a $\mathcal{G}$ by letting $\mathcal{G} = \phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi$. To check $\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi \in \text{Aut}(G)$ we need to check $\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi$ is a bijection on $G$ and that its a homomorphism on $G$. Bijection of $\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi$ follows from the composition of 3 bijections. We check homomorphism by considering the action on 2 arbitrary elements of $G$ say $g_1$ and $g_2$. $$\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi(g_1 g_2)=\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}[\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)] = \phi^{-1}[\mathcal{H}\phi(g_1)\mathcal{H}\phi(g_2)]=\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi(g_1)\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi(g_2)$$
>      By homomorphic properties of $\phi$, $\phi^{-1}$, and $\mathcal{H}$. Thus $\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi \in \text{Aut}(G)$. We just need to check that the element of $\text{Aut}(G)$ so defined will send us to the given $\mathcal{H}$. $$\Phi(\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi) = \phi\phi^{-1}\mathcal{H}\phi\phi^{-1} = \mathcal{H}$$
> 3. Let $\mathcal{G_1}$,$\mathcal{G_1} \in \text{Aut}(G)$. Then:
>      $$\Phi(\mathcal{G_1}\mathcal{G_1})=\phi\mathcal{G_1}\mathcal{G_1}\phi^{-1}=\phi\mathcal{G_1}\phi^{-1}\phi\mathcal{G_1}\phi^{-1}=\Phi(\mathcal{G_1})\Phi(\mathcal{G_2})$$

Comment: Remember that the composition of two homomorphisms is always a homomorphism

Comment: where did I use that and not realize it?

Comment: I'm saying you don't use it when you should. In two places you check whether or not the maps you defined are homomorphisms, but you can just note that they're compositions

Comment: aha, thanks for pointing this out. i would have gone on verifying this for the rest of my life, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, apart from one particular. It can also be simplified.

First, prove that, for $\alpha\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, $\phi\alpha\phi^{-1}\in\operatorname{Aut}(H)$: this is essentially obvious (but is missing from your proof). Thus $\Phi$ is well defined.

Second, prove that $\Psi\colon\operatorname{Aut}(H)\to\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ defined by $\Psi(\delta)=\phi^{-1}\delta\phi$ is the two-sided inverse of $\Phi$. Note there's no need to check $\Psi$ is well defined, because it's the same argument as above with $G$ and $H$ swapped. Thus $\Phi$ is bijective.

Third, prove $\Phi$ is a homomorphism (your check is right).

Comment: sorry, I'm still new at proofs. What does it mean for a map to be well defined?

Comment: @yoshi You have to verify that $\phi\alpha\phi^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $H$ to begin with. Easy, but necessary.